# How do I place k points in an area A, such that the distance between any two points is maximized?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, minimax

I'm planning a garden right now, and as such, let's say I have 6 tomatoes I want to plant in a garden with dimensions `l` by `w`. Tomatoes in my area are affected by blight, so maximizing distance between tomato plants is very important for maximizing my overall yield.

I've been thinking the obvious solution is something like this:

```
T---------T--------T
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
T---------T--------T
```

with `T` representing the location of a tomato. Then I thought the solution might be related to Steiner trees, as shown quite well in this video from singingbanana: https://youtu.be/dAyDi1aa40E

That solution might look like this:

```
T------------------T
.                  .
.                  .
.      T      T    .
.                  .
.                  .
T------------------T
```

But perhaps that solution is also minimizing distance. I'm not really sure, but I'm guessing this is a problem with a known solution that I could employ for this use case!

Comment: "Minimizing distance" of what?  If you don't know whether you want to maximize or minimize the distances between the plants, you're in pretty bad shape.

Comment: You might try iterative algorithms. At each step, try to slightly increase the distance of one point from the others

Comment: The Steiner tree solution is minimizing distances, so it's not useful for solving the problem. If we assign a size to the rectangle, say 20x10, then the distance between plants in the obvious solution is 10, but the distance between plants in the Steiner solution is less than 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called "circle packing" and a best algorithm for it is an open problem.  Even a best algorithm for the case the rectangle is a square is still open.  (Though in fact we have proved optimal solutions for packing 1-30 circles in a square.  But not for 31.)

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701/how-many-circles-of-a-given-radius-can-be-packed-into-a-given-rectangular-box for some discussion of this.

The optimal general arrangement for lots of circles and a large area is a hexagonal packing like in a honeycomb.  In your diagram drop the top middle circle, and raise the bottom corner circles.  You will find that, for many rectangles, you can now fit larger circles.

For the special case of 6 circles, I would simply provide a list of different packings to try, try each and see how big it could be packed that way.  In fact I would suggest only trying two.  The first is the hexagonal packing that I described above.  The second is to take your image and slide the bottom corners towards the left and the top ones towards the right.

Comment: Clever insight! What if I wanted to allow circles to pass through the border? Is that simply a case of packing an `l+2r by w+2r` rectangle? Or is there more nuance? Intuitively I'd say the former, but my intuition around these things is not very strong.

Comment: @ijustlovemath The former. :-)